# Problems passing parameters in PL/SQL from php

Tags: php, plsql

It's the first time I'm developing an application pl / sql and I have some difficulties to pass parameters to php pl / sql. The functions PL / SQL are already created in the database and when run the following query, it returns due parameters:

```
BEGIN 
  PIN_USERNAME := 'admin';
  PIN_PASSWD := '1';
  POUT_MESSAGE := NULL;

  RetVal := PKG_LOGIN.LOGIN_PORTAL ( PIN_USERNAME, PIN_PASSWD, POUT_MESSAGE );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PIN_USERNAME='||PIN_USERNAME);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PIN_PASSWD='||PIN_PASSWD);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('POUT_MESSAGE='||POUT_MESSAGE);
  COMMIT; 
END;
```

Now the problem is I can not do the same in php. Here is the code in php that I developed with the help of google:

```
include 'define.php';
require_once '../config/connectDB.php';
if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['senha']))
{
    $utilizador = $_POST['user'];
    $senha = $_POST['senha'];
    $msg;

    //Connection database
    if(!ligacaoDB())
    {
        echo "Dont Connect";
    }

    $query = "begin :r := PKG_LOGIN.LOGIN_PORTAL (:1, :2, :3); commit; end;";    
    $result = oci_parse(ligacaoDB(), $query);     
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ":1", $utilizador);
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':2', $senha);
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':3', $msg);
    oci_bind_by_name($result, ':r', $r);
    $xpto = oci_execute($result);


    if($xpto == false)
    {
        $e = oci_error($result);
        print htmlentities($e['message']);

    }
    else
    {
        echo $msg . " | " . $r;
    }
    oci_free_statement($result);
    oci_close(ligacaoDB());
}
```

From what I understand plsql function, this parameter receives the `user` and `password` checks whether the database and returns a message and a boolean which were represented by `msg` and `r`.

Does someone can help me and explain to me who might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? What's actually happening? Also, why are you committing a login?

Comment: I'm login to check if user exists in the database. Unfortunately I have to use the functions already set in plsql. The error it gives me at the moment is the following: `ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored`. I think that will be the attribute `:3`, which was to give it `null` but if you do get an error page to return

Comment: What is the datatype of `RetVal` variable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you discovered the reason. For those who have the same problem here is that I answer:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci03typ.htm#CEGIEEJI

> The following two types are internal to PL/SQL and cannot be returned
> as values by OCI:
>
> Boolean, SQLT_BOL
>
> Record, SQLT_REC